# Unknown reference to value named ''. Currently known value names are: []

Tags: google-earth-engine, batch, extract

I'm extracting an imagecollection with to drive with this function :

```
 var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');
 var output_folder = 'Modis_tiff';

// Export collection image to Drive
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(
  simpleJoinedCollectionM, // colorado_collection
  output_folder, 
  {
    name: '{system_date}', // {id}, {system_date} and all other properties (e.g., {WRS_PATH})
    // dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd', // Default
    //scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    region: ROI, // rmnp_boundary, 
    type: 'float' // 'float', 'byte', 'int', 'double', 'long', 'short', 'int8', 
                  // 'int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'uint8', 'uint16', 'uint32'
  }
);
```

But I got this error : Unknown reference to value named ''. Currently known value names are: [].
On top of that I just got a few image of my image collection available to exctract. Do someone know how to deal with this ?
Here is my full code (! when running the code gee freeze for ~ 30 minutes so put the code to excract the dataset in comment to run it fast)
https://code.earthengine.google.com/f413dc2a757272d708a9912357fa892e

Comment: You will need to provide a much simpler example to reproduce your error.   suspect that perhaps the error is related to the images not having the `system:time_start` property assigned.